# CrossFadeColor not working from dark to white

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, cross-fade

This i do not understand, and I don't know how to make this work...

I am trying to make a panel image color fade from a dark green to white like this:

```
myPanel.GetComponent<image>().CrossFadeColor (colorToFadeTo, fadeTime, true, true);
```

This do not work... It seems like it keeps the base color (green) and then puts the other color into that color :-/

Can anyone help me with this... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find much information on CrossFadeColor, but I do know it would work as you expect with [Color.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html) since it will change the color, not add it.

You will have to do it in a coroutine, or the Update.